# What is a color sensor and where do you get it?

Tags: mindstorms, sensor-colour

I have an NXT but I don’t know how to make it detect colors, all it does is say “wait”. My set includes a light sensor but I heard some YouTube videos say there was a lego “color” sensor. Does LEGO sell this? Can some one tell me how to get it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lego has made colour sensors for various robotics themes, including Boost, EV3, and NXT. NXT is pretty old so you'll need to head to a 3rd party website like [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=color%20sensor#T=P) to buy one.

Answer (score 4):

The [Original Mindstorms NXT](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8527-1&name=Mindstorms%20NXT&category=%5BMindstorms%5D%5BNXT%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) only came with the [NXT Light Sensor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=64078#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). The NXT Light Sensor *cannot* detect colors, so this is most likely what you have. You can currently purchase the [NXT Color Sensor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9694-1&name=NXT%20Color%20Sensor&category=%5BMindstorms%5D%5BNXT%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from [Bricklink.com](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page) for under $30.